# Material-components-web : How to increase width of a Tempory Drawer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, frontend

## Material-components-web : How to increase width of a Tempory Drawer ?

Hello

I have a little problem regarding [Material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)

In the demo avaible [here](http://material-components-web.appspot.com/drawer/temporary-drawer.html), i woul like to expand the size of the Temporary drawer to add some column.

I tried to modfiy the width or set a negative margin in the right but it doesn't work in this case.

Can somebody help me on that subject ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please include a fiddle of what you've done so far, where you are stuck, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i'm assuming you want to expand the width of the expanding drawer. After a bit of analysis i noticed there was a max-width set on the navbar. So we'd have to remove that first with javascript. I did it this way.

```
var element= var element = document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-
temporary-drawer__drawer')[0];
element.style.maxWidth='none';
```

After this i could apply any width that i wanted. So if you want to apply a width of 500px, you could :

```
element.style.width='500px';
```